# Angular 13 custom element won't render JSON input in html

Tags: json, angular, element

I am building a generic ui dropdown element in angular. I have built a custom class definition that it will accept as an input to render the details of the dropdown:

```
export class Dropdown {
  labelName: string = '';
  tableSource: string = '';
  propertyName: string = '';
  options: DropdownOption[] = [];
}
export class DropdownOption {
  listOrdinalPosition: number = 0;
  propertyValue: number = 0;
  propertyDisplayValue: string = '';
}
```

Omitting some of the boilerplate, the data-dropdown.component.ts is setup as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'data-dropdown',
  templateUrl: 'data-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['data-dropdown.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class DataDropdownComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public descriptor: Dropdown;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // ensure dropdown has at least one option
    if (this.descriptor?.options.length < 1) {
      console.error('dropdown descriptors must have atleast one option');
      return;
    }

    this.currentValue = this.descriptor?.options[0].propertyValue;
  }
}
```

I am unable to get anything from the `descriptor` input to render in HTML. Currently, the data-dropdown.component.html is:

```
<div *ngIf="descriptor">
  <label>{{descriptor.labelName}}</label>
  <!--<select>
    <option *ngFor="let o of descriptor.options"
            [ngClass]="{'selected' : currentValue === o.propertyValue}">{{o.propertyDisplayValue}}
    </option>
  </select>-->
</div>
```

I'm calling this element from a parent element as:

```
<data-dropdown [descriptor]="infinityDropdownData"></data-dropdown>

// infinityDropdownData is a Dropdown type JSON
```

The entire `<select>` is commented out but I am starting with trying to get the label to work. When I debug the data-dropdown.component.ts:ngOnInit() function I see that the descriptor property has the data I expect:

[image]

The html doesn't get rendered, as shown below:
[image]

I believe what I'm trying to achieve should be possible: create a reusable custom angular element that accepts a complex json. I have seen various similar questions related to this issue with no real conclusive solution. Thanks for any help in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. Using this as a component rather than an element allows rendering of the json as I expect.

I removed the "element" registration from app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  entryComponents: [
    DataDropdownComponent
  ]
})

export class AppModule {
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    const dropdownEl = createCustomElement(DataDropdownComponent, { injector: injector });
    customElements.define('data-dropdown', dropdownEl);
  }
}
```

Then it began to work